# Why is np.load not able to load a file saved using np.save() without allow_pickle=True

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pickle

I am trying to save 2d array as npy file using np.save(). It saves without any error and without using any pickling.But when i load the file , I am getting the following error traceback as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "final_model.py", line 144, in <module>
    a=create_bags('abnormal')
  File "final_model.py", line 130, in create_bags
    video_feature=np.load(DATASET_ROOT+'train/features/'+flag+'/'+file)
  File "/home/aditya_vartak_quantiphi_com/anaconda3/envs/v/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 452, in load
    return format.read_array(fid, allow_pickle=allow_pickle,
  File "/home/aditya_vartak_quantiphi_com/anaconda3/envs/v/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 739, in read_array
    raise ValueError("Object arrays cannot be loaded when "
ValueError: Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False
```

I researched about it on internet , only to find one statement saying something like,

`Array might not be loaded properly , that's why np.load is considering it as object array`

So what i did is made a test code for that file(lets call it `error_file`) as follows:

```
f_b=feature_extractor(file_loc)
np.save(target_path,f_b)
feature=np.load(target_path)
print(feature, feature.shape)
```

This gives results as expected without throwing error

but when i use it inside a function which takes in all features npy files one by one and loads it to print its contents, the execution of function stops at the exact point where it encounters
`error_file` with the traceback as above

The test code should have replaced the wrongly formed feature npy with right one, but the error dont seem with the file , but with np.save itself.
Addendum: The Function works for all npy files before it, even though they all went through same procedure during feature formation

Any help would be great

Comment: `allow_pickle` is default True for `np.save`, but default False for `np.load`.  Their respective docs explain why.  So it could have used `pickle` without telling you.  Note the version date for the change in `np.load`.

Comment: Evidently in the larger context, a file contains an object dtype array.  That could result from saving a none array object, or array built from arrays of differing shapes.  Allow pickle and check the results.

Comment: I forgot to update here, but issue was that code was reading some other file but printing this file's name. the other file was NULL

Comment: I found in another SO question that `load` of an empty file produces this pickle error, even though it should produce an `IOError`.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/62596678/901925