# Python 3 numpy.load() until End of File

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, serialization, deserialization

Suppose I'm generating a random number of arrays that I need to serialize

```
def generator():
    num = 0
    while num < random.randint(0, 10):
        yield np.array(range(2))
        num += 1


with open('out.npy', 'wb') as f:
    for item in generator():
        np.save(f, item)
```

Now how do I know exactly how many times I have to `np.load()` to get all the arrays back? `np.load()` will eventually throw an exception so I came up with

```
with open('out.npy', 'rb') as f:
    try:
        while 1:
            item = np.load(f)
            print(item)
    except:
        print("EoF")
```

but I wonder if there is a way to detect End of File or just a better way to do this.

Comment: You are using an undocumented feature of np.save/load.  Nothing has kept track of how many arrays you've strung together.  Reading till you get an EOF exception is perfectly fine Python.  But you should refine your `except` clause so it catches just that.  And do something to collect all those `item` arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj yeah this is just sample code to illustrate the problem. I actually followed the last example at [numpy.save](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) to save/load but found myself in this use case where I don't know the actual number of saved items.
By the way the exception raised is `ValueError: Cannot load file containing pickled data when allow_pickle=False` after exausting every element.

Comment: If `np.load(f, allow_pickle=True)` you get `EOFError`.

Comment: Your generic `except` was hiding this `ValueError`, which has nothing to do with your EOF.  One or more of your arrays was saved as object dtype, possibly because it wasn't an array to start with, or contained lists/arrays of differing sizes.

Comment: @hpaulj no man, the code raising ValueError is the code you see in the question. ValueError is probably raised because having exhausted every item it tries to read something that can't be read. You can try the code yourself it doesn't take that long.

Comment: OK, looking at the `np.load` code, I see that it's handling of an empty file is a bit sloppy, conflating this `pickle` test with a true `IOError`.  If it can't find the expected `npy` magic prefix, it tries to load the file with `pickle` - provided it has permission.  It returns the `IOError` (that I expected) if that fails.  The pickle test is new since I last looked a repeated loads.  In any case, you are trying to use an undocumented feature; so expect some rough edges.

Comment: @hpaulj Oh cool thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following?

```py
data = np.load('out.npy')
```

reference: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.load.html

Comment: Yes, it only loads the first array.
I followed the last example at [numpy.save](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) and according to that you have to `np.load()` everytime you want to get the next element.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What is the the array you would like saved in the first place, something like this: `[array([0, 1]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 1])]`

what is saved to out.py in the OP code is very different than what is saved when calling `np.save('out.py', data)`

Comment: As I said it's like the last example of the link I posted, which is saving an array at a time in the opened file. The only modification I need is that the arrays to be saved are a random amount (and are yielded by a generator but that doesn't really matter).
In short your code would work if you were to save an allocated list of array, but that's just not my use case.